# Django fails to import _ssl when deployed to IIS

Tags: python, django, windows, iis

I am trying to host a Django application (Django 2.1.4, Python 3.6) using IIS on an older windows server (Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1). I've successfully deployed it on a testing server (same OS) and it is ready to be deployed to production, but I'm running into issues here. I followed the same configuration steps that I used on the staging server, however now when I try to reach the main site I am given the following error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` when it tries to import _ssl (full stack trace below). This is a requirement to use Okta authentication as well as to enable email through the site.

I have installed all dependencies in a virtual environment and configured IIS to use that environment. I've done this with multiple venvs and a conda environment, all with no luck. If I comment out the parts of the code that use Okta, the app works just fine until I get to a point where it sends an email to a user, at which point I face the same issue. Additionally, if I use Django's development server using `manage.py runserver` both Okta and email functionality work flawlessly. I've also made sure that the app is running as a user with full permissions to both the app and virtual environment. I've also been able to confirm that _ssl.pyd is in fact in the virtual environment.

I'm assuming that for some reason IIS is not able to locate or access _ssl.pyd, so if anyone has an idea of why that would happen, or what else could be causing this, I'd definitely appreciate the help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 605, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = handler()
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 34, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\mmitcdba\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\mozilla_django_oidc\middleware.py", line 21, in <module>
    from mozilla_django_oidc.auth import OIDCAuthenticationBackend
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\mozilla_django_oidc\auth.py", line 20, in <module>
    from josepy.jwk import JWK
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\josepy\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from josepy.interfaces import JSONDeSerializable
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\josepy\interfaces.py", line 8, in <module>
    from josepy import errors, util
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\josepy\util.py", line 4, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 172, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "C:\ACD_Django\envs\django\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 142, in init_static_locks
    __import__("_ssl")
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.



StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, but it ended up being a problem with the version of Python I was using. I switched jobs so I don't have access to check what the exact versions were, but I realized that the instances where it was working were all running one Python version behind. Once I downgraded it worked fine. Unfortunately I'm not really sure why that fixed things though.